# How to write and read org.joda.time.Date in Parcelable class

Tags: android, jodatime, parcelable

I am creating a class that Implements the Parcelable,.

```
public class PosicaoResumoMobile implements Parcelable {

private Float _Latitude;
private Float _Longitude;
private org.joda.time.DateTime _DataHora;
    ...
```

But this class has an attribute of type org.joda.time.DateTime. 
How can I write this attribute in the following method implementing the Parcelable since it is not possible out.writeDateTime (_DataHora).

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) 
{
    //TODO: How to write org.joda.time.DateTime 
    out.writeFloat(_Latitude);
    out.writeFloat(_Longitude);
}
```

and read

```
private PosicaoResumoMobile(Parcel in){
    //TODO: How to read org.joda.time.DateTime 
    Float latitude = in.readFloat();
    Float longitude = in.readFloat();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to get the milliseconds using `getMillis()`

```
// to write to parcel
out.writeFloat(_Latitude);
out.writeLong(jodaDTInstance.getMillis())

// to read from parcel
Float longitude = in.readFloat();
jodaDTInstance = new DateTime(in.readLong());
```

Comment: Okay, but the timezone information included in `DateTime` will be lost this way (and chronology, too).

Comment: @MenoHochschild The same way you can pass a date string including the timezone.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @artworkad comment, if you need to include Timezone information, you will have to use toString() and DateTime.parse():

To write to parcel:

```
dest.writeString(mDateTime.toString());
```

To read from parcel:

```
mDateTime = DateTime.parse(in.readString());
```

Answer (score 0):

tray this code kotlin :

write :

```
out.writeSerializable(myDateObject)
```

read :

```
myDateObject =  in.readSerializable() as Date
```